# Can multiple blocks and threads write to the same output?

Tags: cuda

I have the following CUDA kernel code which computes the sum squared error of two arrays.

```
__global__ void kSquaredError(double* data, double* recon, double* error, 
                               unsigned int num_elements)
{
    const unsigned int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    for (unsigned int i = idx; i < num_elements; i += blockDim.x * gridDim.x) {
        *error += pow(data[i] - recon[i], 2);
    }
}
```

I need a single scalar output (error). In this case, it seems like all threads are writing to error simultaneously. Is there some way I need to synchronize it?

Currently I'm getting a bad result so I'm guessing there is some issue.

Comment: If your videocard can do atomic operation `atomicAdd`, try it. Otherwise you need blocking (and there would be no sense from multithreading).

Comment: Thanks, I used `atomicAdd` (for float though) and it seems good. Write your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: You could use parallel reduction algorithm instead of atomicAdd to maximize the performance. There's sample code of parallel reduction in the cuda sample dir.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation you are doing now is subject to race conditions due to the fact that all threads try to update the same global memory address at the same time. You could easily put a `atomicAdd` function instead of `*error += pow...` but that suffers from performance issues due to it being serialized on each update.

Instead you should try and and do a reduction using the shared memory, as following:

```
_global__ void kSquaredError(double* data, double* recon, double* error, unsigned int num_elements) {
    const unsigned int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    const unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x;
    __shared__ double serror[blockDim.x];//temporary storage of each threads error

    for (unsigned int i = idx; i < num_elements; i += blockDim.x * gridDim.x) {
        serror[tid] += pow(data[i] - recon[i], 2);//put each threads value in shared memory
    }

    __syncthreads();

    int i = blockDim.x >> 1; //halve the threads
    for(;i>0;i>>=1) {//reduction in shared memory
            if(tid<i) {
                serror[tid] += serror[tid+i];
                __syncthreads();//make shure all threads are at the same state and have written to shared memory
            }
    }

    if(tid == 0) {//thread 0 updates the value in global memory
        atomicAdd(error,serror[tid]);// same as *error += serror[tid]; but atomic
    }
}
```

It works by the following principle, each thread have its own temporary variable where it calculates the sum of the error for all its input, when it have finished all threads converge at the `__syncthreads` instruction to ensure that all data is complete.

Now half of all the threads in the block will take one value from the corresponding other half add add it to its own, half the threads again and do it again until you are left with one thread(thread 0) which will have the total sum.

Now thread 0 will uppdate the global memory with an atomicAdd function to avoid race condition with other blocks if there is any.

If we would just use the first example and use atomicAdd on every assignment. You would have `gridDim.x*blockDim.x*num_elements` atomic functions that would be serialized, now we have only `gridDim.x` atomic functions which is a lot less.

See [Optimizing Parallel Reduction in CUDA](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/gilesm/cuda/prac4/reduction.pdf) for further reading on how reduction using cuda works.

### Edit

Added if statement in the reduction for loop, forgot that.

Comment: @Ran forgot to add a if statement in the reduction loop, should work now

Comment: `atomicAdd` only works for float, and you can't declare an array size with `blockDim.x` since it's not a constant.